# Dynamics CRM 2015: Send email upon bulk deletion completion

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Can I configure Dynamics CRM 2015 to email notifications upon bulk delete jobs without code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of box option is there for sending job completion notification email to scheduler as well as extra recipients.

That email will include direct link to bulk deletion job also.

[image]